# Giving files from a remote server a specific id

Tags: php, ftp

I am working on a subscription page. On this page, user A can subscribe to their favorite albums. If user B uploads an album, then user A will be able to download that new album. However, he can only download those albums to which he has subscribed. Other albums should not be visible. We show a list of albums that have been uploaded, they can download it once they subscribe

To achieve this, I was thinking about giving each new album an automatic id once they are uploaded. However, I do not know if this is possible since the albums are coming from a remote FTP server. It would also be impossible because I would have to write an if statement for every id:

```
if($id == 1) {
  //do display;
} else {
  // do not display;
}
```

And I, of course, I do not want to do that.

My question: How can I make sure that user A can only see those files that he has subscribed to? How can I do this since the files come from a remote FTP server (I can already retrieve them)?

PS. I have not written code yet, I am thinking about how I can accomplish this.

Comment: Use a database to track which files each user can see.

Comment: But I want the files to be saved on the remote server

Comment: Then save address information to the database too.

Comment: This question is still a bit too vague. You state that user A can subscribe to an album that hasn't been uploaded yet. How is that going to work?

Comment: We show a list of albums that have been uploaded, they can download it once they subscribe

Comment: So, if I understand it correctly, something only becomes an album after it has been uploaded. And only then can an user subscribe to it.

Comment: yes, it does. User A can subscribe to the uploaded albums. He can only see the albums he subscribed too. And he can see them on the downloadpage

Comment: The obvious thing to suggest is to use a database to keep track of the users, albums and subscriptions. I don't see the word "database" anywhere in your question therefore that is going to be my suggestion. See: [a tutorial](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-introduction.php).

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, the data needs to be saved in the remote FTP server :(

Comment: That is a bit silly, and will slow down your website quite a lot, and probably make it unreliable, but it is possible. You could use one, or multiple, SQLite database(s) in PHP. These are databases that can be stored in a single file, in the location of your choosing. Perhaps it's best to use PDO to interact with the database, that will make it easier to switch to another database later.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware. If I do it in one single database as you said before. Will I be able to make sure that the data that gets inserted in the remote FTP-server, also gets inserted in the database.

Comment: Well, you are planning to make quite a weird setup, so don't ask me for any guarantees. It's up to you to build in the proper checks.

Comment: Let's just do it the way you told me. If I save the data in the database. Can I then also insert it in the database

Comment: There is no need for the database to be saved on the FTP server if you're saving the location of the albums in the database.

Comment: @JayBlanchard. I do not want to save the database in the FTP server. I want the files to be saved in both the remote FTP server and in the database. How can I do this?

Comment: Which files do you want saved?

Comment: The mp3 files that are in my remote FTP server right now. I want them to also be saved on the database so that I can give them an id. Or anything that makes sure user A can only see the files he subscribed to. Anyways, a DB is needed.

Comment: You do not need to save the MP3 file to the database, you only need to save its location and name to the database. That way you can create a link to the download.

Comment: I would still need a DB for that. I want the path and name to be saved on both DB and remote FTP server. Also, if you have a definitive answer. Write it down as an answer.

Comment: Ah, I see, I though you said you wanted to save the database on the FTP server. But now I think you didn't mean that.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, No. I want the files to be saved on both the remote FTP server and the DB :).

Comment: Why do you need the name and path saved on the FTP server? It makes no sense?

Comment: No, on the DB. Not the remote FTP server @JayBlanchard

Comment: You just said *"I want the files to be saved on both the remote FTP server and the DB"*

Comment: Oops, I made a mistake. On the remote FTP server, they already are saved (not the path and name). I can already upload the files to the remote FTP server. I just want the path and name to be saved only on DB.